# ComboBox items in full-mode and normal-mode

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I want to show an accent color chooser like what is built-in in the system.

When It's in full mode, I want it to appear as tiles with available colors, and when it appears as a drop-down list, I want it to appear as a little square and color name next to it.

The problem is that I don't know how to set two templates for full-mode and drop-down mode.

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="AccentColor_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Yellow" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Yellow" />
            </Grid>
        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Blue" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Blue" />
            </Grid>
        </ComboBoxItem.Content>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

This works only for drop down mode. How can I achieve it? (It's a Windows PHone Runtime app).

Comment: Here was the only place I found some information and digging about this:

http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/05/22/Migrating-from-the-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ListPicker-to-the-new-XAML-ComboBox-(Display-a-ListPicker-in-XAML-apps).aspx

Answer (score 0):

normally in wp8 when number of items in a dropdownlist becomes more than 5 items it will automatically turns to a full screen mode.else it will show in just a drop list..

In listpicker there is a property call ExpantionMode..try that or following link will help you..

```
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868195.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..just edit as per your requirement.

I have just pasted my code.

```
<wpToolkit:ListPicker Name="cmbCountry"  Background="#FFF9E2"  Foreground="#333333" Grid.Column="0"  ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"  SelectionChanged="cmbCountry_SelectionChanged_1">
    <wpToolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryName}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
           </DataTemplate>
     </wpToolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
     <wpToolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <Border BorderBrush="#FFF9E2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="425">
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryName}" FontSize="35"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                  </Border>
           </DataTemplate>
    </wpToolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```